# Possible issues after updating from Magento 2.1.X to Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-upgrade

If I will upgrade **Magento 2.1.0 to Magento 2.2** then is there any possible issues which I have to take care after upgrade process?

Will site work smoother or do I have to compromise with some functionality?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with custom extension which was using custom tables with serialized fields

In Magento 2.1 default `php serialize` function is used.

In Magento 2.2 `json serialize` is used and trying to unserialize old entites will end up with error

> Error: Unable to unserialize value.

You need to check your custom modules if you are extending default Magento functionalities or overriding classes using `<preference>`

Magento official guide to convert serialized data to 2.2 Thanks to  @Swapnil Tatkondawar
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html

Comment: I had issues with layout validation in custom theme and serialized data after Magento 2.2 upgrade. 

Magento have provide solution for serialize issue.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html

Answer (score 1):

You may have **Undefined offset error** after upgrading. You can check such issue here in github https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11412

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [list of backward-incompatible changes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html) in 2.2.0 from DevDocs.